# on click of anchor tag its first changes the URL it redirect but comes back to top of the page and on second click it redirect to section

Tags: javascript, html, angular

**Is There any javascript through I can prevent this thing from doing this behavior**

```
** 
                    <li *ngFor="let item of TitleList">
                        <a href="{{item.Link}}">
                            <div class="icon_img"></div>
                            <h1>{{item.Name}}</h1>
                        </a>
                    </li>
```

**

Comment: please elaborate your question it appears to be some js issue but you have only provided html code here.

Comment: as I redirecting to section id through the anchor tag but it always comes back to the top of the page after going to that particular part and also changes the URL with like http://url/#id after this on the second time click its redirect to that particular section